# Determine if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\exp(1/n)}$is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have problem figuring out if this series is convergent or divergent. Please help!

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\exp(1/n)}$$

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

as n goes to infinity , $ e^{\frac{1}{n}} $ goes to 1. So your limit of summand goes to 1.. Therefore it should be divergent.

Comment: Reread the OP. It's $e^{-\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: It's just the same result, @ZachL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the Divergence Test to show that this infinite series diverges.

The theorem states that if a series ${a_n}$ does not converge to $0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ diverges.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{n}}} = \frac{1}{e^0} \to 1 \ne0 \implies a_{n} \ \  \text {diverges}$$